# Play gifs sequentally in Android Studio

Tags: android, gif

I'm trying to play **two or more** gifs in Android Studio. I'm using gif image view, but everytime I try to play more gifs in it, it displays only the last one. I can't find a way to play all of the gifs sequenatally. Any ideas please?

```
List gifs = Arrays.asList("gif1", "gif2", "gif3");

GifImageView gifView = view.findViewById(R.id.gifView);

for (int i=0; i < gifs.size(); i++) {
    String word = gifs.get(i);

    int idNum = getResources().getIdentifier(word, "drawable"
              getActivity().getPackageName());
    gifView.setImageResource(idNum);
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to play more than one gif into an imageView??

Comment: @sreehari It already occured to me that I might be using wrong view, but I didn't find any alternative to it so far.

Comment: Please provide some more information about the way you load gifs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a loop to load gifs into the view, all gifs except the last one will be overwritten on each iteration, you should load the next gifs only after completely playing the gif.

Here is an example of achieving this using Glide and ImageView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int gifLoaded = 0;
    List gifs = Arrays.asList("https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/708/675/4b5.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/tOH34YVvpq4AAAAC/malayalam.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/AKtcHf4ZTAsAAAAC/malayalam-kerala.gif"
    );

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadImage();

    }
    private void loadImage() {
        if (gifLoaded > gifs.size() - 1) {
            gifLoaded = 0;
        }
        String url = (String) gifs.get(gifLoaded);
        ImageView giv = findViewById(R.id.iv_gif);
        Glide.with(this).asGif().load(url).listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                resource.setLoopCount(1);
                resource.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
                        gifLoaded++;
                        loadImage();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        }).into(giv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried putting delay at the end of the loop, but that just made the app behave in a weird way. I also tried searching for some way to make the app wait until the current gif finishes, but no luck.

Comment: Can you please share the library you are using

Comment: pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView;